# How to Add "Go to App" Button to Existing Page

Tags: facebook, admin

I have a Facebook page that I would like to associate with a new app, so that I can have the "Go to App" button on this page. It doesn't seem like there is any way to associate a new app to an already existing page. In the app advanced settings there is only the option to Create a Page - but I don't want to create a new page, since I already have a very large following (number of Likes) on my existing page.

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: adding an app to a page tab ? if you mean this look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684334/how-to-embed-fbapp-within-fbpage-in-a-specific-way/10685352#10685352)

Answer (score 0):

No work around I'm afraid. When Facebook first introduced the feature to "Create A Page" for an app, they let you create a Page with type "App" and let you add it to the app. It looks like this function has been removed as you have to create a new page.

But, you can use the `Migrate Pages` function to then combine the two pages into one, but you will lose the content on the old page when you move it to the new one.