# Can I add a "Go to App" button to my Facebook page, or migrate my page to an app community page?

Tags: facebook

I would like to have a Facebook page for my Facebook app with a "go to app" button.  The problem is, our existing page does not have such a button.

One option would be to add the button to the page.  Is there a way to do that?

The other option would be to create an app community through the developer app, and migrate the likes and URL from the old page.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610766/how-to-add-go-to-app-button-to-existing-page