# How to embed fbApp within fbPage in a specific way?

Tags: facebook, url, get

how can I embed my app in my facebook page in a way as here:
www.facebook.com/SzkolaSTRAMA?v=app_323694844330149

I have attached the app to my page using the magic url:
http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=&pages=1&page=

and tried to open somehow the app within using the v parameter, but it seems it is not that. Can someone give me a clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can add an application to a page in a page tab by going to below mentioned url

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

You need to change "app_id" with your app_id, you can find it in app settings, "Your_url" should be replaced with your application complete url for e.g. "https://www.facebook.com/TestApplication?sk=app_389610254390000"

after changing values press enter, If you are admin of any Facebook page then you will be taken to a screen where you can select the page, after completion of this step your app will be added to page tab.

For further clarification go to this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

`YOUR_URL` should be replaced with your Canvas url. 
(The page that is being loaded into iframe on facebook)

`APP_ID` with id of the Page Tab application.

Explained also here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10535905/1520297